# Where to put files for a command-line Java program?

Tags: java, bash, shell, command-line

I have written a Java program that takes in arguments and then executes. I pass in these arguments from the command line (I am on a Macbook Pro using Terminal, using the bash shell). Let's say the name of my program is prgm. I want to be able to say "prgm " from any directory in the shell and then have that program execute. So I figure I need to write a bash script to reference the Java files and take in arguments, and put that bash script somewhere in my PATH. Where do I put the bash file, and where do I put my Java files? Also, am I right to assume that I only need the .class (binary) Java files?

Comment: Since you know that you must put the bash script in your PATH, you can answer the first question ("where do I put the bash file") yourself. All other files can be referenced from the bash script.

Comment: @laune I know it has to be somewhere in my PATH, but where specifically? In my usr/local/bin or somewhere else? Also, I get that I need to reference my java files from there, but where should I be keeping the files? I'm thinking of this from a perspective of "if I had a download program button, where would I install everything?"

Comment: It depends: are you alone on your system or are there other users? Do you need to share the program or is it for exclusive use?

Comment: I am alone on my system, but I would like to implement this in such a way that users who are not alone on a system can also download this program with no problem. The program does not need to be shared between users.

Comment: Then /usr/local/bin is the typical place for programs to be used by all users on a system. The Java stuff should go into a subdirectory of /usr/local/lib, preferably as a jar file. BUT: if you want to distribute your SW, you should provide an installation where these choices are up to the installer. Such rules may vary from system to system.

Answer (score 1):

Step-by-step:

1. Assuming that the name of the Java executable if `myjavaprog`.
2. Assuming that the name of your bash script is `myscript`.
3. Make sure `myscript` is calling `myjavaprog` using absolute path and the desired arguments.
4. call `echo $PATH` and you will see a bunch of paths: `/some/path1:/some/other/path2:...`
5. Put your bash script in whatever path you want from the ones returned by `echo $PATH`.
6. Go to a random path.
7. Call you bash script `bash myscript`. See the execution of `myjavaprog`.

*Tips:*

- If java program is for personal use only, put it in a path starting with `/usr/` or even in your `$HOME` directory (and add that location to your `PATH`)
- If java program must be shared with other users, put it in an accessible place, so that other users don't need to modify their `PATH` variable.

Comment: Does it matter which path in $PATH that I but my bash shell in? Also, what is the convention on where to put my Java files? For example, if I were to make a download program link, what is the convention for where would everything go?

Comment: Hi Adrian! There could be a lot of various recommendations, more or less depending on each user's preference. But, since we've touched the topic of the linux fie-system hierarchy, you could check the official info [here](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/Linux-Filesystem-Hierarchy/html/) and [here](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/intro-linux/html/sect_03_01.html). I can give 2 hints: if you use a server (a machine shared between many users), put your personal stuff in your `$HOME` directory and update your `$PATH`. If, on the other hand, this is your personal computer, simply experiment!